# Search word in string with javascript

Tags: javascript

I search a certain word in a string correctly in this way:

```
let text = jsonDesc.plain_text;

const product = 'Producto:';

const resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)'))[1];

console.log( resultProduct ) // Mesa
```

But how can I search the string if sometimes the word is lowercase and other times uppercase?

I tried this:

```
     var product = 'Producto:';
     var productU = 'PRODUCTO:';

     var resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product && productUpper + '\\s(\\w+)'))[1];
```

And:

```
var resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp( '^[a-zA-Z]' + product + '\\s(\\w+)'))[1];
```

But dont works, error:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null at VueComponent.getAllProducts**

Answer (score 1):

You can use case insensitive matching (i) as a [regex flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters).

```
new RegExp(expression, 'i');
```

In your case this would look like `text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)', 'i'))[1];`

However I would recommend not just appending the product to the expression due to it possibly containing special regex characters in it. For instance right now you have a colon in there which could cause problems. If the `product` is fixed I would just rewrite your code to be

```
var product = 'Producto';
text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\:\\s(\\w+)', 'i'))[1];
```

Alternatively [escape the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript#answer-3561711) before appending it to the rest

```
function escapeRegex(expression) { return expression.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'); }
var product = 'Producto:';
text.match(new RegExp(escapeRegex(product) + '\\s(\\w+)', 'i'))[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert all strings to lowercase, then check if the string includes the searched word

```
let product = 'Producto:'
let productU = 'PRODUCTO:'
let match = product.toLowerCase().includes(productU.toLowerCase())

console.log(match)
```